# Pythonwin - print function not working

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm running pywin32 build 216.1 and am having trouble using the simple print function - for example:

```
>>> print 'Hello!'
```

should return:

```
Hello!
```

but instead I get:

```
Traceback (  File "<interactive input>", line 1
    print 'Hello!'
                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

It doesn't matter what I try and use with print, it gives me this same error.  I am able to do other things just fine as long as they don't involve the use of the print function. Can anyone help?

Comment: What version of Python are you running?  In 2.x print is a statement and can be used as `print 'Hello!'`.  In 3.x it is a function and should be called as `print('Hello!')`.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In Python 3, print is a function, not a statement.  Call it like:

```
print("Hello!")
```

Comment: Jay, pywin32 is not a version of Python, it's just the GUI and editor. The underlying interpreter is probably Python 3.2.0 or 3.2.1 if you just downloaded it.